# Header content и footer с нефиксированной высотой на всю высоту экрана

Tags: html, css

Постараюсь объяснить.

Есть 3 блока, хедер, контент, футер. Дело в том, что ничего из этого не фиксированной высоты. Высота хедера динамична. Высота футера динамична. Футер прижат к низу. Между ними контент высота которого меняется в зависимости от хедера и футера. Т.е. Контент - тупо блок, занимающий пространство межу хедером и футером. Страница не будет скролиться. (При переполнении будет скролиться блок, который будет внутри блока контента, но это не суть важно, у меня проблема в расположении блоков).

Я вот тут набросал

```css
body{
 background-color: #ff0;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
.header{
 background-color: #f00;
}

.footer{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
 background-color: #f0f;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="header">header</div>
 <div class="footer">fo<br>ot<br>er</div>
</body>
```

Я, конечно понимаю, что для нормального взаимодействия футер не должен быть абсолютным. Но идеи у меня закончились. Контента тут нет, но он должен покрывать то, что остаётся жёлтым.

Если можно - без флексов. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов на flex

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: stretch;
}

header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  flex-grow: 0;
  background-color: #f00;
}

main {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  flex-grow: 2;
  background: orange;
}

footer {
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #f0f;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">


    <header>headerfo<br>ot<br>er</header>
    <main>mainfo<br>ot<br>er</main>
    <footer>footerfo<br>ot<br>er</footer>
  </div>
</body>
```